# Why is global + shared faster than global alone

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I need some help understanding the behavior of [Ron Farber's code](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/cuda-supercomputing-for-the-masses-part/208801731?pgno=2).

I don't understand how the use of shared memory is giving faster performance over the non-shared memory version.  I.e. if I add a few more index calculation steps and add another Read/Write cycle to access the shared memory, how can this be faster than just using global memory alone?  The same number or Read/Write cycles access global memory in either case.  The data is still accessed only once per kernel instance.  Data still goes in/out using global memory.  The number of kernel instances is the same.  The register count looks to be the same.  How can adding more processing steps make it faster.  (We are not subtracting any process steps.)  Essentially we are doing more work, and it is getting done faster.

Shared memory access is much faster than global, but it is not zero (or negative).
What am I missing?

The "slow" code:

```
__global__ void reverseArrayBlock(int *d_out, int *d_in) {
    int inOffset  = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int outOffset = blockDim.x * (gridDim.x - 1 - blockIdx.x);
    int in  = inOffset + threadIdx.x;
    int out = outOffset + (blockDim.x - 1 - threadIdx.x);
    d_out[out] = d_in[in];
}
```

The "fast" code:

```
__global__ void reverseArrayBlock(int *d_out, int *d_in) {
    extern __shared__ int s_data[];

    int inOffset  = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int in  = inOffset + threadIdx.x;

    // Load one element per thread from device memory and store it
    // *in reversed order* into temporary shared memory
    s_data[blockDim.x - 1 - threadIdx.x] = d_in[in];

    // Block until all threads in the block have written their data to shared mem
    __syncthreads();

    // write the data from shared memory in forward order,
    // but to the reversed block offset as before
    int outOffset = blockDim.x * (gridDim.x - 1 - blockIdx.x);
    int out = outOffset + threadIdx.x;
    d_out[out] = s_data[threadIdx.x];
}
```

Comment: What card are you running this on? It can make a significant difference.

Comment: And by significant different, older cards only support reading global memory efficiently when in your "forward order" mode. Newer cards shouldn't suffer from this though. (I believe this changed somewhere around when 2.x was released)

Comment: The article was written in 2008.  The HW is pre-Fermi.  I'd term this as and 'older' card.

Comment: Igor's answer covers what I was referring to. Your card would need to be a bit older than pre-fermi as well. But it would match with what you're seeing perfectly. Nvidia also publishes methods to see how many coalesced reads and writes you are doing. See: http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/nvidia-visual-profiler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Early CUDA-enabled devices (compute capability < 1.2) would not treat the `d_out[out]` write in your "slow" version as a coalesced write. Those devices would only coalesce memory accesses in the "nicest" case where `i`-th thread in a half warp accesses `i`-th word. As a result, 16 memory transactions would be issued to service the `d_out[out]` write for every half warp, instead of just one memory transaction.

Starting with compute capability 1.2, the rules for memory coalescing in CUDA became much more relaxed. As a result, the `d_out[out]` write in the "slow" version would also get coalesced, and using shared memory as a scratch pad is no longer necessary.

The source of your code sample is article "CUDA, Supercomputing for the Masses: Part 5", which was written in June 2008. CUDA-enabled devices with compute capability 1.2 only arrived on the market 2009, so the writer of the article clearly talked about devices with compute capability < 1.2.

For more details, see section F.3.2.1 in the [NVIDIA CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

this is because the shared memory is closer to the computing units, hence the latency and peak bandwidth will not be the bottleneck for this computation (at least in the case of matrix multiplication)

But most importantly, the top reason is that a lot of the numbers in the tile are being reused by many threads. So if you access from global you are retrieving those numbers multiple times. Writing them once to shared memory will eliminate that wasted bandwidth usage

Comment: There is no data reuse here.  It is read from a unique global once, it is written to another unique global once.  The same number of global accesses happen in both chunks of code.  i.e. The same global bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at the global memory accesses, the slow code reads forwards and writes backwards. The fast code both read and writes forwards. I think the fast code if faster because the cache hierarchy is optimized in, some way, for accessing the global memory in descending order (towards higher memory addresses).

CPUs do some speculative fetching, where they will fill cache lines from higher memory addresses before the data has been touched by the program. Maybe something similar happens on the GPU.

Comment: The CC 2.0 and 3.0 data cache hierarchy does not prefetch. Prefetch is supported through software instructions (see PTX manual). SM to L1 are accesses are use 128B transactions. L1 to L2 accesses use 32B transactions. Uncached L2 (not cached in L1) can be done using 32B transactions.